# How to handle javascript error from vbs?

Tags: javascript, pdf, vbscript, error-handling, adobe

I'm trying to put watermarks to pdf file. I wrote vbs script. It works, but when pdf is signed, my script can't add watermark.
VBS "On Error Resume Next" and Err object doesn't provide error info...
How to catch js error?

Here's  part of .vbs script

```
...
Set objPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
objPDDoc.Open(dpath & fileobj.Name)
Set jso = objPDDoc.GetJSObject
Call jso.addWatermarkFromText("text", jso.app.constants.align.left,  "Arial", 14, jso.Color.blue, 0, jso.numPages, True, True, True, jso.app.constants.align.left, jso.app.constants.align.bottom, 0.4, 35, False, 0.9, False, 0, 1)
...
```

and error (on string with 'Call jso.addWatermarkFromText')

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: C:\pdf_sign_frd\print_sign.vbs
Line:   463
Char:   4
Error:  NotAllowedError: Запрещен доступ к данному свойству или методу.
Code:   800A03E9
Source: Acrobat JavaScript
```

Comment: Not sure if this needs the JavaScript tag, since the source code is VBscript.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Why do you think it's not in the err object, In VBScript things bubble up till it finds an error handler. As VBScript didn't handle it, WSH did (by crashing) when it bubbled from VBScript to WSH. Remember COM calls are really - `HResult = FunctionName(Inparm1, ..., Inparmn, OUTPARAM)`.

Comment: VB shows the above as `OUTPARAM = FunctionName(Inparam1, ..., Inparamn)` with `HResult` put into the `err` object.

Comment: The JavaScript tag is important here because the JSO is a bridge to the Acrobat JavaScript interpreter. The error is coming from that interpreter and, unfortunately, can only be interpreted in that context. You'd need to know what is causing the JavaScript error to understand what's wrong with the VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

The "securityHandler" property will tell you if the file is protected and  can't be modified. Document security and signatures will set the securityHandler to something other than null. When it's null, the watermark can be applied.

```
If IsNull(jso.securityHandler) Then
...
End If
```